# Third party jars appearing twice in runtime classpath

Tags: java, jar, eclipse-pde

I am trying to implement a bundle that uses the SLF4J logging facade following the pattern outlined on nogunner's blog [here](http://blog.kornr.net/index.php/2008/12/09/understanding-the-osgi-logging-service).

I have packaged the SLF4J implementation files as a jar that I want deployed as 3rd party jars in my application bundle along with the SLF4J api jar.

The problem is: when I do this, SLF4J is complaining that the StaticLoggerBinder (which implements the SLF4J static factory classes is appearing twice in my classpath. It seems that both my library jars are being deployed twice into the bundle class-path.

I've reviewed and followed ([here](http://robertvarttinen.blogspot.ca/2007/01/adding-third-party-jar-to-your-eclipse.html) and posts on this site) solutions for including third party jars.

Here are the details:

```
Eclipse Standard/SDK
Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819
```

Here's my manifest. The `lib/osgi.slf4j.impl-1.0.0.jar` has the custom binder, factory and logger implementations. The other jar is just the SLF4J api distribution.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Logging
Bundle-SymbolicName: dsct.equinox.log.frontend
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: dsct.test.useLog.Activator
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.7.0",
 org.osgi.service.log;version="1.3.0"
Bundle-Classpath: lib/osgi.slf4j.impl-1.0.0.jar,
 lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar,
 .
```

Here's the build file:

```
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               lib/
source.. = src/
```

And from this I get the following SLF4J errors:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://1.fwk899805279/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://1.fwk899805279:3/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [null]
```

which I believe is telling me that the StaticLoggerBinder is contained in both the first and third Bundle-ClassPath entries.

Here's what's odd:

- If I switch the order of the lib/ jars in the manifest, then the error messages reflect the change in order - and shows the duplication occurs in classpath entries 2 and 4 respectively.
- If I Export the bundle - it looks fine: proper manifest, proper lib\ with 2 jars

So it really looks to me like the build is doubling up the bundle-classpath jars. When my runtime class-path looks like (number indicates the classpath index):

```
osgi-slf4j: 0
slf4j-api:  1
.           2
```

I get the duplication showing up at indexes 0 and 3 implying the path looks like:

```
osgi-slf4j: 0
slf4j-api:  1
.           2
osgi-slf4j: 3
slf4j-api:  4
.           5
```

When the runtime classpath order looks like this:

```
.           0
slf4j-api:  1
osgi-slf4j: 2
```

The error messages indicate the duplication occurs at entries 2 and 5, so it looks like the classpath is:

```
.           0
slf4j-api:  1
osgi-slf4j: 2
.           3
slf4j-api:  4
osgi-slf4j: 5
```

PS: I've done project->clean and have turned on "clear configuration before launching" and included `-clean` in the program arguments. I've also used PDE Tools -> Update Classpath

Any suggestion on how to get to the bottom of what's going on?  I've looked for ways to inspect the built / deployed bundle and can't find anything. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Thanks....

**Further clarification**

The osgi-slf4j jar is my implementation of an SLF4J implementation and the version numbering is mine. It has nothing to do with the osgi-over-slf4j bridge from the log4j folks.

I wrote a bit of code in the bundle activator to get the bundle class loader and list the classpath resources. The list is:

```
bundleresource://4.fwk899805279/
bundleresource://4.fwk899805279:1/
bundleresource://4.fwk899805279:2/
bundleresource://4.fwk899805279:3/
bundleresource://4.fwk899805279:4/
bundleresource://4.fwk899805279:5/
```

which seems to confirm my suspicion that my classpath has twice the number of that it should. Why does the manifest have 3, yet dumping the classloader resources show six?

When I remove the osgi-slf4j jar and place its source directly into my src directory everthing works fine!!?? And, classpath dump looks like this:

```
bundleresource://4.fwk899805279/
bundleresource://4.fwk899805279:1/
bundleresource://4.fwk899805279:2/
bundleresource://4.fwk899805279:3/
```

which is 4 entries rather than the two I was expecting

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issues. Your detailed explanation helped me track down the problem:
A plugin's "Java build classpath" and "PDE classpath" (MANIFEST.MF) seem to be merged when deployed in an OSGI container via Eclipse Launch/Debug. This explains the duplication of bundle resources in the bundle class loader.

**Workaround:**
Removing the SLF4J binding JAR from the "Java build classpath" will resolve the multiple bindings error.

I am pretty sure this is a bug, but a quick research in Eclipse Bugzilla did not yield any results.

Comment: Here is the Eclipse bug report for this issue: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=417869 Your method works for me but I now get errors on the "Problems" tab stating the classes aren't included in the plugin. It does work fine when run however, is just messy to have those errors show up in the Eclipse environment.

Answer (score 0):

Being included multiple times is not the problem you are having, the problem is that you have two incompatible implementations of the library see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings to see which library combinations it expects.

Comment: Not sure about that - the osgi=slf4j jar is a **custom** built slf4j implementation, built by me based on the nogunner blog code, so you can ignore the version number, it's my versioning and has nothing to do with the osgi-over-slf4j bridge produced by the log4j folks.

Comment: @user2925382 The library complains it finds two StaticLoggerBinder but you could be right that this is the same class twice and OSGi is confusing the detector of this condition.

Comment: thanks, fyi, I added some further clarification and investigation at the end of the original post.